# Integrate a function of three variables C++

Tags: c++, numerical-methods, scientific-computing, numerical-integration

I spent quiet some time looking on the internet to find a solution to this, maybe it's out there but nothing of what I saw helped me.

I have a function !

```
double integrand(double r, double phi, double theta)
```

That I want to integrate with some given definite bounds over the three dimensions. I found multiple lines of code on the internet that implement single variable definite integrals numerical schemes. I was thinking to myself "well, I'll just integrate along one dimension after the other".

Algorithmically speaking what I wanted to do was :

```
double firstIntegral(double r, double phi) {
    double result = integrationFunction(integrand,lower_bound,upper_bound);
    return result;
}
```

And simply do it again two more times. This works easily in languages like Matlab where I can create functions handler anywhere but I don't know how to do it in C++. I would have to first define a function that some r and phi will calculate integrand(r, phi, theta) for any theta and make it in C++ a function of one variable only but I don't know how to do that.

**How can I compute the triple integral of my three-variables function in C++ using a one -dimensional integration routine** (or anything else really...) ?

Comment: if you know how do it in matlab but not in c++, then why do you want to integrate using c++ ?

Comment: You could use lambdas, `std::function`, `std::bind` or just plain function pointers.

Comment: Perhaps it would be clearer what you intend to do if you showed how you would achieve what you want in matlab.

Comment: "A function of one variable only". Do you perhaps mean a lambda closure?

Comment: @tobi303 I did it in Matab already because it was only to validate a model but now I have to implement said model into an existing software from the company I work for

Comment: @user2079303 not sure it would be of great help, in Matlab you just have to do 
   integral3(integrand,a1,a2,b1,b2,c1,c2) 
where a, b, c are the respective bounds

Comment: @Ari0nhh  I don't know anything about lambda closure, I'll look this up

Comment: @JeremyDiallo well that makes sense. Btw the comment was just out of curiosity. I also love matlab for prototyping

Comment: @tobi303 It's the best language for scientific research so far, you just type what you think and it works

Comment: @JeremyDiallo unless you need the algebra power of mathematica ;)

Comment: I think Julia has quite expressive power for science with modern language features.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking, but maybe `bind` is what you're looking for?

Comment: The [Cuba](http://www.feynarts.de/cuba/) library performs numerical quadrature in N dimensions. It includes Monte Carlo algorithms that are useful when `N>>1`. The [Cubature](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/Cubature) library only offers deterministic algorithms, but is easier to use. GSL offers 1D quadrature routines, which could be composed to build multidimensional integration routines (see the [scipy.integrate.nquad](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/5edce54b2efe0304a14cc77336957baabdd6e04e/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py#L582) for an implementation).

Answer (score 1):

This is a very slow and inexact version for integrals over cartesian coordinates, which should work with C++11.

It is using std::function and lambdas to implement the numerical integration. No steps have been taken to optimize this.

A template based solution could be much faster (by several orders of magnitude) than this, because it may allow the compiler to inline and simplify some of the code.

```
#include<functional>
#include<iostream>

static double integrand(double /*x*/, double y, double /*z*/)
{
  return y;
}

double integrate_1d(std::function<double(double)> const &func, double lower, double upper)
{
  static const double increment = 0.001;

  double integral = 0.0;
  for(double x = lower; x < upper; x+=increment) {
    integral += func(x) * increment;
  }
  return integral;
}

double integrate_2d(std::function<double(double, double)> const &func, double lower1, double upper1, double lower2, double upper2)
{
  static const double increment = 0.001;

  double integral = 0.0;
  for(double x = lower2; x < upper2; x+=increment) {
    auto func_x = [=](double y){ return func(x, y);};
    integral += integrate_1d(func_x, lower1, upper1) * increment;
  }
  return integral;
}

double integrate_3d(std::function<double(double, double, double)> const &func,
                    double lower1, double upper1,
                    double lower2, double upper2,
                    double lower3, double upper3)
{
  static const double increment = 0.001;

  double integral = 0.0;
  for(double x = lower3; x < upper3; x+=increment) {
    auto func_x = [=](double y, double z){ return func(x, y, z);};
    integral += integrate_2d(func_x, lower1, upper1, lower2, upper2) * increment;
  }
  return integral;
}


int main()
{
  double integral = integrate_3d(integrand, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  std::cout << "Triple integral: " << integral << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll try your code. So if I already defined a function `double integrand(double r, double phi, double theta)`, I just have to make it `static` and use your code right? Sorry I'm pretty illiterate in C++ but I have to develop on it anyway right now...

Comment: You can use this with both static and globally linked function ("static" only changes the visibility of the function outside its translation unit). So if the function is not intended to be used outside the translation unit, make it static, otherwise declare it in a header file and use ordinary linkage.

Comment: Thank you, and why were x and z commented in the function arguments listing ? What does it mean ?

Comment: Also, I have the error `Symbol function could not be resolved` at the lines with expressions like `std::function`. As I said I'm a C++ illeterate, I included the libraries `functional` and `iostream` I don't know what to do

Comment: I just commented out the argument names because I compiled with -Wall -Wextra and was not using the argument names in the example. Otherwise the compiler would have warned about unused arguments. I am sure your function uses the arguments.

Comment: Regarding the symbol: what build chain are you using? Which Compiler, Linker, IDE? And where do you get the error from? Linker or IDE?

Comment: I'm using the eclipse IDE for C/C++ developers, I'm using MinGW GCC 4.8.1 and Gnu Make Builder, I don't have a choice for these tools I'm working on a version of a software source code in my company that was poorly developed and can only be compiled using this specific build chain. I first got the error from the IDE parser but tried to compile anyway as I thought that maybe it was a glitch specific to the IDE but I have errors when compiling  like `function is not a member of std`, `std::function has not been declared`, `expected , or ; before } toke`and several other errors

Comment: add the option -std=c++11 to the compiler and probably also linker options. (CXXFLAGS and LDFLAGS)<functional> was introduced with C++11 and gcc 4.8 defaults to an older standard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148600/discussion-between-jeremy-diallo-and-paulr).

Comment: I can't access the chat right now, I'll try to add the compiler and linker options and tell you what it does thank you

Comment: I don't know how to add options to the compiler or the linker on Eclipse... This is so annoying to have to develop on a language that I don't understand...

Answer (score 0):

You can use functors

```
#include <iostream>

struct MyFunctorMultiply
{
    double m_coeff;

    MyFunctorMultiply(double coeff)
    {
        m_coeff  = coeff;
    }

    double operator()(double value)
    {
        return m_coeff * value;
    }
};

struct MyFunctorAdd
{
    double m_a;

    MyFunctorAdd(double a)
    {
        m_a  = a;
    }

    double operator()(double value)
    {
        return m_a + value;
    }
};

template<class t_functor>
double calculate(t_functor functor, double value, double other_param)
{

    return functor(value) - other_param;
}

int main()
{
    MyFunctorMultiply multiply2(2.);
    MyFunctorAdd      add3(3.);

    double result_a  = calculate(multiply2, 4, 1); // should obtain 4 * 2 - 1 = 7
    double result_b  = calculate(add3, 5, 6);      // should obtain 5 + 3 - 6 = 2

    std::cout << result_a << std::endl;
    std::cout << result_b << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is just about getting the right prototype to pass to the integration function, you can very well use alternative data passing mechanisms, the simpler of which is using global variables.

Assuming that the order of integration is on `theta`, then `phi`, then `r`, write three functions of a single argument:

`It(theta)` computes the integrand from the argument `theta` passed explicitly and the global `phi` and `r`.

`Ip(phi)` computes the bounds on `theta` from the argument `phi` passed explicitly and the global `r`; it also copies the `phi` argument to the global variable and invokes `integrationFunction(It, lower_t, upper_t)`.

`Ir(r)` computes the bounds on `phi` from the argument `r` passed explicitly; it also copies the `r` argument to the global variable and invokes `integrationFunction(Ip, lower_p, upper_p)`.

Now you are ready to call `integrationFunction(Ir, lower_r, upper_r)`.

It may also be that `integrationFunction` supports a "`context`" argument where you can store what you want.

Comment: For more orthodoxical programming, you can probably make the global variables private static class members.